# Is “be confident in your capacity” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, north-american-english

I'm trying to learn some new English recently, is this sentence grammatically correct?

> Be confident in your capacity.

Does it sound weird to say? To me it seems like when saying capacity some actions need to be followed, like “the capacity to create”.

Comment: This sentence sounds incomplete as a stand-alone sentence. What kind of capacity? It would be OK if there was leading context.

Comment: Sentences can be grammatical without meaning anything. A well-known example is "[Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)"